# The program will know the time span if else vb.net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I dont know how it is called thats why I called it time span.
I don't have any idea yet how to code it but this is what i want to do

```
Dim sy as String

If (June 2015) to (March 2016) Then

sy = "2015-2016"

End if
```

I know it is simple but i dont know how to code the June 2015 to 2016

Thanks in advance  for the help

Edit :
Now i got to this code

I uses to do this

```
Dim value as DateTime = New DateTime(2017, 4, 1)
Dim value1 as DateTime = New DateTime(2018, 4, 1)

    Dim sy as String
    If my.computer.clock.localtime <= value then
    sy = "2016-2017"
    ElseIf my.computer.clock.localtime <= value1 then
    sy = "2017-2018"
    Else
    msgbox("Check your current date")
    End if
```

But when the computer's time changed to 2015 it shows "2016-2015"

Comment: Use two `Date`-variables or put them into a new class with a `StartTime` and `EndTime` property.

Comment: ... or use this library: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET

Comment: Can you give me example code I dont have any idea yet about that

Comment: Turn on Option Strict.  `sy` is going to end up being `"1"`.

Comment: I forgot to put "" sorry its "2015-2016"

Answer (score 0):

So I use 4 textboxes to supply the data you need as variables. 2 for the years and 2 for the months. Also you need to think of how many moths left in the yeae and add the month number of the next year. If you span more than one year you have to account for this as well. O.K here is the snippet without error checking in a button event:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim firstÝear As Integer = CInt(TextBox3.Text)
    Dim secondYear As Integer = CInt(TextBox4.Text)
    Dim firstmonthnumber As Integer = CInt(TextBox5.Text) 'months number in first year
    Dim secondmonthnumber As Integer = CInt(TextBox6.Text)
    Dim d1 As DateTime = New DateTime(firstÝear, firstmonthnumber, 1)
    Debug.Print(d1.ToString)
    Dim d2 As DateTime = New DateTime(secondYear, secondmonthnumber, 1)
    Debug.Print(d2.ToString)
    Dim M As Integer = Math.Abs((d1.Year - d2.Year)) - 1
    Debug.Print(M.ToString)
    Dim myYear As Integer = 12 - firstmonthnumber 'month left to the end of first year
    Dim months As Integer = ((M * 12) + Math.Abs((d1.Month - d2.Month))) + myYear
    Debug.Print(months.ToString)
End Sub
```